# Determining if a set of vectors is a basis for a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that I need to determine linear dependency to find if it is a basis, but I have never seen a set of vectors like this. How do I start this and find linear dependency. I have never seen a vector space like $\mathbb{R}_{3}[x]$
Determine whether the given set is a basis for the vector space. Let
(a) $S={1+x,1+x^2,1−x^3,1+2x+3x^2},V =\mathbb{R}_{3}[x]$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Hint : if you want to bring back to 'familiar' vectorial space just note that $\mathbb{R}_{3}[x]$ is a vectorial space of dimension 4 over $\mathbb{R}$, since $\mathcal{B} = \left\lbrace 1,x,x^{2},x^{3}\right\rbrace$ represent a basis for it.

Once you noticed this, you could define the isomorphism of coordinates which just send a basis into a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, for example the canonical one :

$$1 \to \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, x \to \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, x^{2} \to \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, x^{3} \to \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now you just have to do write you 'old' vectors in this new basis and check linear dependancy as always.

(Note : there is a better basis choice which will avoid to do further calculus)

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve the equation:
$$a(1 + x) + b(1 + x^2) + c(1 - x^3) + d(1 + 2x + 3x^2) = 0$$
for $a, b, c, d$, bearing in mind that we have equality as functions of $x$. That is, $x$ is not an unknown we solve for, but instead the above has to hold true for *any* $x$. This opens up some possibilities.

One of my favourite tools for this job is differentiation. Since the left and the right are equal as functions of $x$, we can safely differentiate both sides with respect to $x$. In fact, if we differentiate three times, most of the polynomials will disappear, giving us:
$$a \cdot 0 + b \cdot 0 + c \cdot (-6) + c \cdot 0 = 0 \implies c = 0.$$
Now our equation simplifies to
$$a(1 + x) + b(1 + x^2) + d(1 + 2x + 3x^2) = 0.$$

We could differentiate twice to get a relationship between $b$ and $d$:
$$a \cdot 0 + b \cdot 2 + d \cdot 6 = 0 \implies b + 3d = 0.$$
We could get another relationship between $b$ and $d$ simply by substituting the specific value $x = -1$, to make $1 + x$ be $0$ and eliminate the $a$ term:
$$a(1 + (-1)) + b(1 + (-1)^2) + d(1 + 2(-1) + 3(-1)^2) = 0 \implies b + d = 0.$$
Solving these two equations simultaneously gives $b = d = 0$, leaving us with
$$a(1 + x) = 0.$$
We can finish this off by either differentiating once, or substituting $x = 0$. In either case, we get $a \cdot 1 = 0 \implies a = 0$, proving linear independence.

(Note that this doesn't prove the polynomials form a basis on their own; you need them to be spanning too. But, if you know that $P^3$ has dimension $4$, then you can use the fact that any $4$ linearly independent vectors in a $4$-dimensional space is a basis.)